# libv4l2 error when using webcam with USB 3.0

Tags: usb, webcam, uvc

I'm experiencing a problem when trying to use a webcam with my USB 3.0 ports.
I have no problem using the USB 2.0 ports.

I get the following error in guvcview or cheese:

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Invalid argument
```

I get a similar error in camorama:

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error reading: Invalid argument
```

I've tried two different webcams (MS LifeCam HD-6000 and Logitech HD 615), and got the same result. Other devices seem work fine plugged into the USB 3.0 ports.

Does anyone know how what to try to get the webcams working with those ports?

-Thanks in advance

Comment: If you unplug the camera, run `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so` and plug it in again, does it work?

Comment: No, same result.

Comment: Try `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so cheese`

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so cheese` yields the same result.